# Find in Mongoose from a query object retrieved from a querystring

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, server-side

I take a querystring from a URL and parse then map it so I get an object like this:

```
{ '$and': [ { length: { '$gt': '2' } }, { length: { '$lt': '55555' } } ] }
```

Which is a const named q.

So how would the Mongoose find query look like? I tried this:

```
  Schema.find(q, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
```

But it gives back empty lists ([]). Upon console logging q, this prints to the console:

```
{ '$and': [ { length: [Object] }, { length: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: console like this `console.log(%j, q)` and then see the query string

Comment: There's no j in my code

Comment: here %j print nested objects in json

Comment: I mean I know the object created is valid, because if I print q.$and, it prints out "{ '$and': [ { length: { '$gt': '2' } }, { length: { '$lt': '55555' } } ] }"

Comment: so now you need to check with the database you query seems to be ok

Comment: There's only one document in the collection, which is { "_id" : ObjectId("5c0e168727a849c54d8d3840"), "smashingText" : "aaa", "length" : 3, "letterCounts" : null, "sentiment" : 5, "date" : "12-10-1902" }. The length property of this is 3, so it should be returning this doc but for some reason it's just returning an empty []

Comment: Here, you are querying on the schema, it should be exported model instead. @J.Doe

Comment: I'm querying on the model, I just wrote Schema as a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

> --fix --  use value as a number because in your database length is cast as a number

```
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      length: {
        "$gt": 2 // not '2'
      }
    },
    {
      length: {
        "$lt": 55555 // not '55555'
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/aJVF9QfDeKy

Comment: I can't change the way the query object is given to me, it's done by a helper function I'm not supposed to alter.

Comment: How could I change the strings to ints from q?

Comment: with the help of `Number('2')`

Comment: Wouldn't the comparison work even if they're strings? Ie '5555' > 4 is true

Comment: (Nodejs) here `string`automatically cast to Number, so `'55555'` assume by the compiler is `number` so that's why you get `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
 const q= { '$and': [ { length: { '$gt': '2' } }, { length: { '$lt': '55555' } } ] }

// converting string key to integer

q['$and'].map(function(obj) {

    for(var prop in obj.length){
        if(obj.length.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj.length[prop] !== null && !isNaN(obj.length[prop])){
            obj.length[prop] = +obj.length[prop];   
        }
    }
});

console.log(q)

Schema.find(q, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
```

Comment: How is it helpful {'$gt': '2'} writing gt with strings? the operand is stored as a number in the collection.

Comment: @ Shivam Pandey , this will convert `{'$gt': '2'}` to `{'$gt': 2}`